# osx: remove all characters from string that cannot be used for a filenames in osx

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

Is there some standard method to remove all characters from string that cannot be used for a filenames in osx? Does the characters you are allowed to use correspond to some commonly used category? (I know defining a list of allowed characters would be possible, but I want to be able to use filenames from several languages (chinese, among others), so this will be a bit of a pain.) A solution that works in ubuntu too, would be great.

Comment: In linux: only two characters(`NULL` and `/`) are not allowed.

Comment: and, assuming you are processing paths as part of filenames, you only really need eliminate any NULL chars. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code to convert a arbitrary string into a valid filename. It follows similar rules (if not the same) to those applied to creating a webloc file when dragging a URL  to the Desktop.

```
// Returns a sting representing this filename transformed (if neccesary) to make
// a valid (Mac OS X) filename.
- (NSString *) stringByMakingFileNameValid:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSMutableString * validFileName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:fileName];
    if (!validFileName || [validFileName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return @"untitled";
    }
    // remove initial period chars "."
    if ([validFileName hasPrefix:@"."]) {
        NSRange dotRange = [validFileName rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]];
        [validFileName deleteCharactersInRange:dotRange];
    }
    // remove any colon chars ":" (same as webloc creation behaviour)
    [validFileName replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [validFileName length])];
    // this may lead to spaces at either end which need trimming
    validFileName = [[[validFileName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] mutableCopy] autorelease];

    // if there is nothing left return default value
    if ([validFileName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return @"untitled";
    }
    // replace other disallowed Mac OS X characters
    [validFileName replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"-" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [validFileName length])];

    // if grater than 102 chars reduce to 101 and add elipses
    if ([validFileName length] > 102) {
        [validFileName deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(100, [validFileName length]-100)];
        [validFileName appendString:@"…"];
    }

    return [[validFileName copy] autorelease];
}
```

At the Darwin level "/" characters are stored as ":" characters (and vice versa). They are removed here for cosmetic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Any unicode character except for the "/" is allowed. Because your question is AppleScript related as well I have to inform you that Macintosh Paths displays a "/" while the actual character is ":". So when you tell the Finder to make folder at path "Macintosh HD:Users:shortname:Desktop:images/movies" then in POSIX it will look like "/Users/shortname/Desktop/images:movies".